# Gedit is not working properly (image in question). Why?

Tags: graphics, gedit, text

When I open a text file this happens:

[image: image 1]

If I scroll up or down this happens:

[image: image 2]

Why?
What should I do?

Comment: It was all right before I updated to 17.4.

Comment: Re-install the videocard driver.

Comment: Does it happen only in gedit or also in other apps?

Comment: Only with gedit.